# Perl Module::Load not working as expected

Tags: perl, autoload

Reading the docs for [Module::Load](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Load#SYNOPSIS), I'm trying to reproduce the results shown in the Synopsis section.  But when I run:

```
perl -we 'use Module::Load;autoload Data::Dumper'
```

It complains:

```
Can't locate object method "autoload" via package "Data::Dumper" (perhaps you forgot to load "Data::Dumper"?) at -e line 1.
```

Setup:

- CentOS 7
- Perl 5.16.3
- Module::Load 0.24
- Data::Dumper 2.145

Comment: Also consider using [Module::Runtime](https://metacpan.org/pod/Module::Runtime) if you are going to install something from CPAN as it does not suffer [the same design flaw](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=106128), and just call the import method yourself if you need it -- you will often need imports at compile time: `BEGIN { require_module $module; $module->import }` (this is of course incompatible with deciding whether to load the module at runtime)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Version 0.24 of Module::Load didn't have the subroutine `autoload` (see [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/release/BINGOS/Module-Load-0.24/lib/Module/Load.pm)). Try using just `load` or try upgrading Module::Load.